# Informix and C: How to get the last inserted serial number from bigserial field type

Tags: c, informix

We have a DB with multiple tables having "serial" type column. The legacy C application writes the data to these tables and uses "sqlerrd[2]" fetch the serial number of the data just inserted.

`insert into email(serial_number, email_id) values(0, 'test@test.com')`

Due to serial number getting exhausted we are migrating to "bigserial". However, the above logic of fetching the serial number from "sqlerrd[2]" dont work, since it is of type "integer".

What is the right solution for handling this?

Note: As a work around we are currently making a call to `ifx_getbigserial` to fetch the serial number. However, we are concerned that, there are multiple tables and concurrent transactions as well and we are not sure, how does this API works? This API dont mention table name and our unit testing shows, we get right data, but not sure, is this the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ifx_getbigserial()` function is correct.  It returns the information about the last BIGSERIAL value generated for the current session.  Other sessions will not affect it.  However, if you insert values into multiple tables that each have a BIGSERIAL column, you must retrieve the inserted value via `ifx_getbigserial()` after you insert into each table and before the next insert into either the same table or any other table with a BIGSERIAL column.

Comment: Do you think using a sequence object to generate the value is a better solution rather than using this "function"?

Comment: It's a real function — no quotes needed.  Personally, I'd use the function rather than a sequence, but a sequence is certainly an alternative.  It is not an expensive function to use — it doesn't involve a round trip message to and from the server; it simply pulls some data that is stored in the session information in the client code.

Comment: Which is the system catalog table that keeps track of max serial and bigserial values?

Comment: The information is stored in the table's control information — not in the system catalog.  Sequences are different; some of the information is stored in the `syssequences` system catalog table.